# Some SMB shares unavailable from Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, smb

I've recently upgraded one of the machines in our office to Mountain Lion.  Since doing so, when connecting to (or browsing to via Finder) our Windows 2008 R2 file server, some shares no longer appear in the list of available shares on that server.  Not all shares have disappeared, only five out of approximately fifteen shares are not visible.

This does not appear to be a user rights issue, as the shares do not appear for multiple administrator and non-administrator accounts.  Additionally, the shares were perfectly accessible from the machine pre-ML upgrade, as well as still being accessible from all other OSX machines in our environment.  In other words, the issue appears to be confined solely to our single machine that was upgraded to Moutain Lion.

Has anybody discovered a solution?

Additional information:

- MacBook Pro upgraded from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion
- Server is a member of our AD domain
- Machine is *not* a part of the Active Directory domain
- Credentials used to connect to server include Domain Admin credentials, user account with domain admin rights, and multiple user accounts without admin credentials but with credentials to view the missing shares
- Server is running Window Server 2008 R2
- Machine has no trouble accessing files on our XServe running 10.5 Server
- Essentially, all other variables seem to be constant with no known changes to the network and server infrastructure involved

Comment: [This post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19084423#19084423) at the Apple Forums appears to describe a workaround of using smb://servername/sharename, however this method requires knowing the exact name of the share.  It is still not a fix for viewing the shares via browsing in Finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:  Join the Mountain Lion system to the Active Directory domain.  User can still log in with their local user name, but when connecting to smb://servername, OSX will stop defaulting to .local for credentials.  This is new to ML, and I think it is a bug, but this is the only solution that we have found.

Comment: While I wouldn't consider this an *ideal* solution since there may be reasons that you wouldn't want to add a Mac to your AD domain, I think this is probably the least intrusive solution until Apple fixes this bug.  Changing the share names would probably work, but that could mess up a lot of unknowns for a lot of other people further down the line.

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same issue. At the office you can't see the shares, but connect through smb. Through a VPN this ain't possible. The answer is in the length of the share-name. Mountain lion can only see them if the length of the sharename is 12 characters or less. Seems like a bug to me. Changing the sharenames is what we did to resolve this issue.

Comment: Interesting.  I thought it might be a name size issue, but I was looking for multiples of 8.  My Mountain Lion test user is out of the office today, but I expect her back in the office tomorrow.  I'll perform some independent testing then to try to confirm your answer.